# Make a Login System using VBA with Access Database

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access

[userform for login existing account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXcFH.jpg)

[access database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBnyy.jpg)

as the image links above, i want to ask about how to connect excel and access database. I will make some points about my problems:

> - there are 2 buttons, "Login" and "New Account". For Login, it should be validating both username and password from "login" table, then the fullname of user will be copied.
> - Login for existed user will have a combobox, where they can find their username but not the password.
> - for the "new account" button, it will ask new username, new fullname, and new password(cant post more than 2 photos rn). I still can figured it out how to do that

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=E:\Digital QC Project\Database.accdb;"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "login", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    With rs
            .AddNew
            .Fields("username") = Range("A4").Value
            .Fields("password") = Range("B4").Value
            .Fields("fullname") = Range("C4").Value
            .Update
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

is that possible to work on first and second point?
thanks stackoverflow!

Comment: this is working too without writing in the excel sheets...
                .AddNew
                .Fields("username") = login2.operatorname.Value
                .Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are tying Excel to Access, then bypassing that will be trivial.  So I assume you are not trying to enforce security using Access from excel with this method.

If you are then you need to go back to the drawing board.  You cannot store the credentials in Access and then expect to use them to enforce security later.  Instead, you need to spend some time re-architecting your solution around:

- The security wizard
- MS Access users
- MS Access groups

In addition I would STRONGLY recommend hashing the password with a salt so that it can be tested but not read.  As it is anyone with Excel can probably read the passwords of the users.